# Can anyone explain me the working of a line mentioned in this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, set

Please explain this line from the below code. `num_to_match = sorted(set(grades.values()))[1]`

```
N = int(raw_input())

students = []
for i in range(2*N):
    students.append(raw_input().split())
grades = {}
for j in range(0, len(students), 2):
    grades[students[j][0]] = float(students[j + 1][0])
result = []
num_to_match = sorted(set(grades.values()))[1]
for pupil in grades.keys():
    if grades[pupil] == num_to_match:
        result.append(pupil)
for k in sorted(result):
    print k
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it? "Please explain the [working, written by someone else] code to me" questions are not good for Stack Overflow, because we can't read your mind to know what to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the line as follows to understand it fully: `num_to_match = sorted(set(grades.values()))[1]`

`grades.values()` - returns the list of values from the dict `grades`

`set(grades.values())` - removes the duplicate entries by converting the list into a set

`sorted(set(grades.values()))` - returns the sorted set obtained from above

`sorted(set(grades.values()))[1]` - picks the second element from the sorted list of items.